# How to write data in node with specific id using simpleXML and php

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I found a lot of tuts here on how to get node with a specified id using XPath, and write down data using SimpleXMLElement::asXML.

But is it possible to write data in the node with specific `id` using XPath, but not `foreach` method?

Here's what I have

```
<people>
    <person>
        ...
    </person>
    <person id="17">
        <name>John</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        ...
    </person>
</people>
```

I'm looking something like:

```
$xml->person['id=17']->name = Bill;
```

or

```
$xml->xpath('/person[@id=17]')->name = Bill;
```

and then

```
$xml->asXML(data.xml);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: Is it OK to walk through 18000 lines everytime I need to edit some part of xml data? Or some built in php functions does the same?

Comment: I'm not sure which `foreach` you're talking about, but [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returns an array, I was talking about `foreach`ing that -- Or do you have 18000 nodes with the same ID?

Comment: Oh. Ok, if I get an array returned with XPath, and I will change values there, how it will reflect on my xml object so I could save all data in file?

Comment: You can simply [try it out and see](http://3v4l.org/tvSba).

Comment: @Passerby No need for a foreach-by-reference in that example, as you're manipulating an object not overwriting a variable: http://3v4l.org/e4lWu

Answer (score 0):

As @Passerby points out, [the `->xpath()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returns an array, so the simplest way is to loop over it with `foreach` ([demo](http://3v4l.org/e4lWu)):

```
$nodes=$xml->xpath('//person[@id=17]');
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $node->name="Bill";
}
```

The objects are all linked back to the original SimpleXML parsing structure, so saving the whole thing back to XML will reflect any changes.

Since we know in this case that there is only one element in the result of the XPath, modifying `$nodes[0]` also works - although beware of what will happen if *no* nodes are found ([demo](http://3v4l.org/niWES)):

```
$nodes=$xml->xpath('//person[@id=17]');
$nodes[0]->name="Bill";
```

The most concise version will only work in PHP 5.4, where you can use array subscripts directly on function return values, squashing the above onto one line - again, only use this if you know for sure the element will be found ([demo](http://3v4l.org/aVKdS)):

```
$xml->xpath('//person[@id=17]')[0]->name="Bill";
```